# Integrating Google Calendar API

Tags: android, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm building a project in Android Studio and I want to create and display events of a specific calendar from the user's Google Calendar Account.

I've search intensively and I can not seem to find information about the use of the calendar API specifically in Android.

[Google guide for Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/overview)

Would appreciate if someone could give me a little push to find the right way to do this.

Comment: read [this](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/blob/master/calendar-android-sample/build.gradle) file and explore the sample project. Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to use any existing SDK I recommand you to read these docs:

- [OAuth2 Process](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2)
- [Google CalendarList reference](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList) (You can make direct api calls from here using the right methods and looking the requests for the details)
- [Google Calendar API reference](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/)

You can also use [this](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/) API explorer (but it can be a little bit outdated).

Comment: I've chosen to go [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider) way. The problem with Calendar Provider is that I'm having difficulty finding online material and support, it also seems like a very strange service to use.
I've chosen caendar provider mainly because my app already has authentication done through  Firebase and can not be login by Google Account. I'm afraid it will conflict with my logIn if I ask google authentication for the calendar feature. Do you think it won't have any conflict with the authentication? Do you think it's better to use the API?

Comment: Also, thanks for the help, I cant up-vote your answer because I still don't have enough reputation points

Comment: I'm not familiar with Calendar Provider so I really can't relate on the conflicts possibilities... Also you're welcome, I recognize that if you wanna use Calendar API the doc can be a little light !